# How to perform SKAction in a view controller file

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, sprite-kit, skaction, skscene

Now I am working on a SKScene. I have two ViewController files and I created two scene files which is subview of a SKScene. I know I can perform many SKActions in the scene files. But I want to do some SKAction in the method appEntersBackground: in the file ViewController.m. But it seems the SKActions in this method don't work and I don't know why.

In the ViewController.m file:

```
-(void)appEntersBackground {
    SKAction *action = [SKAction customActionWithDuration:0.1 actionBlock:^(SKNode *node, CGFloat elapsedTime) {
         //perform some actions
    }
    [myNode runAction: action];
}
```

Comment: You need to add more details to get an answer. Is the method being called? Is `myNode` a valid reference to an SKNode object?

Comment: Yes, it will be called every time the app become active again from background. And I think the myNode is valid. it is a SKShapeNode.

Comment: You *think* or do you *know*? If you don't know, confirm that. Set a breakpoint, see if it is nil. Also double check whether it's added as child, and is in the currently presented scene rather than "the other scene".

Answer (score 0):

You cannot perform an SKAction from the viewController. You might however, trigger a method in the scene itself when the application enters the background and perform the necessary operations there.

Paste the appEntersBackground method in the SKScene itself. Then call the following notification in the didMoveToView method.

```
-(void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view {
    /* Setup your scene here */

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(appEntersBackground) name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification object:nil];

    //The rest of your setup goes here

}

-(void)appEntersBackground {
    SKAction *action = [SKAction customActionWithDuration:0.1 actionBlock:^(SKNode *node, CGFloat elapsedTime) {
         //perform some actions
    }
    [myNode runAction: action];
}
```

The method should get called when the application enters the background.